# Is there a way to retrieve information from a ui element that has the property IsControlElement = False? (Python + Appium + WinAppDriver)

Tags: ui-automation, python-appium, appium-desktop, winappdriver

Greetings and salutations!

I'm working on a UI automation project for a windows desktop app (FrameworkId: Win32)
Stack: Python (3.7) + Appium (1.15.1) + WinAppDriver (v1.1).

I have identified an element using Inspect.exe, but when I try to code, whatever I do I receive this error:
**selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.**

The locator strategy I'm using is xpath:
`self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@LocalizedControlType='text' and @IsControlElement='false']")`

As you can see, Inspect.exe has shown that it has the property "`IsControlElement='false'`", but I cannot for the life of me "access" it via code.

I would also like to point out that any elements that had the `IsControlElement='true'` are properly found and I can "interact" with them.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

## Source of issue

This is *probably* an issue within Microsoft's UI Automation implementation in .NET.
The property `IsControlElement` should have returned `true` while it didn't.

From my tests, it seems to be an issue somewhere within `UIAutomationCore.dll`.

I **speculate** that the root cause is that the automation implementation was targeted for accessibility in mind, and they have **mistakenly** ignored some controls which are NOT readable (`Image`, `Geometry`, etc.).

## Workaround for some cases

- Try to use UI control from a type that has a text.
- if it's already a textual control, try to use a **different** textual control type. for example - in `WPF` project - use `Label` instead of `TextBlock`
- if it's NOT a textual element, if possible, wrap the control in a textual element. in `WPF` projects you can use a `<Label Padding="0">` as a wrapper.

## Other things to consider

- Try to use [UIAComWrapper](https://github.com/TestStack/UIAComWrapper)

## Related issues

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46452431/426315
- [UIAutomation won't retrieve children of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187110/uiautomation-wont-retrieve-children-of-an-element/14187618)
- [UI Automation - #32770 (Dialog) shows in Insepct.exe but not in VisualUIAVerifyNative.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904741/ui-automation-32770-dialog-shows-in-insepct-exe-but-not-in-visualuiaverifyn)

## Side Note

Since you haven't specified [which Python GUI library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) are you using, I was not able to provide examples for your library. Sorry.

Comment: Hello Itsho! 
Thank you for your response! The Python GUI library used is win32all if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I've used **pywinauto** to automate the same thing and, what I ended up doing was using "sort of an xpath" approach where I took the .child_window(criteria).children()[x] .children()[y] and the got reached the element I needed to interact with \ read. Is there any way to do from within Appium?

Comment: I mean I know you can access an element with `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@attribute='value']")` but not entirely sure what do from there.

Comment: What I've also found is that if you do try something like this: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@attribute='value']/*")` this would take you to the next node that does have `IsControlElement="True"`, so that's a start anyway.